# Is it okay to add comments to old posts on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I am daily visitor of Stack Overflow and I wonder if it is okay if I add comments on old posts. Say approximately 1 year old post?. I am not sure about it.

Comment: No - comments should not be added to old posts, I would never do it. :-)

Comment: @SilverlightFox How does it feel to be living in the future?

Answer (score 14):

What are you concerned about? What sort of comments do you have in mind?

The question's asker will get notified of the new comment, but they may no longer be active on the site and might not actually *see* your comment or respond to it. But even then, there's nothing really wrong with posting a comment in the first place.